# Can I use Nearby Notification API without registering my beacon with Google Beacon Platform?

Tags: eddystone, google-nearby, google-beacon-platform, proximityapi

I want to push notification to users when in my beacon's proximity. That's pretty easy if I register my beacon on Google Beacon Platform using Proximity Beacon API and then register Nearby Notification against it. I do not want to register the beacon on Google Beacon Platform and still throw a notification to user through Nearby Notification API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to Google Nearby to be triggered by a beacon, **you have no choice but to register the beacon with the Google Beacon Platform**.  That's how it works.  Nearby is a system that relies on server-side configuration to send messages to a user.

That said, it is possible to send regular Android notifications to a user when they come across your beacon without registering with the Google Beacon Platform.  To do this, you must have your own custom app installed on the user's phone.

You can see an example of how to do this with the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library) in the "Getting Notified When Beacons Appear in the Area" section of [this page.](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/eddystone-how-to.html)  A more sophisticated example that scans in the background and sends a notification to the lock screen on beacon detection is in the library's  [reference app.](http://tps://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference)

Comment: You suggested using Android Beacon Library for background scanning of beacons. As for my use case, I was planning to use Nearby Message API since I'm already registering my beacons on Google Beacon Platform. Just for sake of understanding, does Android Beacon Library provide better mechanism to do same as in the background scan. I mean Nearby probably scans only at Screen change events that limits the scan for my app. Is the library better to use?

Comment: The Android Beacon Library is more flexible as to when it scans.  By default, it does a constant low power scan in the background, and a higher power scan briefly every 5 minutes.  You can customize this to suit your needs.

Comment: I was hoping to use my android device as a beacon and send Nearby notification to alert other users that the app is in use in the area and either allow them to open the app or be directed to the app store